# SSRS 2012 Lookup Function Returns No Data

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, lookup

I have an SSRS 2012 Report that is based on a MetricsData dataset that contains the field "REPOSITORY". The report also has a second dataset, PlanITData, containing the fields:

```
RepositoryName
AppName
AppOwnerName
```

I put an expression into one of the report columns containing the following Lookup:

```
=Lookup(Fields!REPOSITORY.Value,Fields!RepositoryName.Value,Fields!AppName.Value,"PlanITData")
```

I expected it would look up the REPOSITORY from MetricsData (the dataset that should be in the scope of the report and does, in fact, display in one of the report columns), find the matching RepositoryName from PlanITData and return the AppName from PlanITData. I get all blanks in this column. I've run the underlying query for the PlanITData dataset with known values and it returns the appropriate values. Do I not understand the Lookup function? This is my first time trying to use it...

Edit: I just saw this warning. I'd swear it wasn't there earlier. No idea what this means:

> Warning   1   [rsLookupOfInvalidExpressionDataType] The Value expression
>   for the textrun ‘LOBGROUP.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ uses a lookup
>   function with an expression that returned a data type that is not
>   valid for the lookup function. The data type must be an RDL Variant
>   type.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the expression above is correct. I kept playing with the datasets and suddenly it started working. Apparently there was an issue with how the datasets were constructed but I'm not sure what it was...